Rails - how to "generate" statistics from hundreds of thousands of data in PostgreSQL database?
I have a model Item with the corresponding database table items where is currently about 240,000 records.
I need to generate statistics from the data in the items table on my dashboard. Currently, I am trying to do it this way:
def dashboard
    if current_user.present?
      @data = Hash.new
      (1..20).each do |n|
        @data[n] = Hash.new
        @data[n]['a_sale'] = Hash.new
        @data[n]['a_lease'] = Hash.new
        @data[n]['b_sale'] = Hash.new
        @data[n]['b_lease'] = Hash.new
        @data[n]['c_sale'] = Hash.new
        @data[n]['c_lease'] = Hash.new
        @data[n]['d_sale'] = Hash.new
        @data[n]['d_lease'] = Hash.new

        tday = Date.today
        yday = tday-1.day

        @data[n]['a_sale']['today'] = Item.where('cat1 = 1 AND cat2 = 1 AND cat3 = ? AND created_at >= ? AND created_at <= ?', n, tday.beginning_of_day.in_time_zone("London"), tday.end_of_day.in_time_zone("London")).count()
        @data[n]['a_sale']['yday'] = Item.where('cat1 = 1 AND cat2 = 1 AND cat3 = ? AND created_at >= ? AND created_at <= ?', n, yday.beginning_of_day.in_time_zone("London"), yday.end_of_day.in_time_zone("London")).count()
        @data[n]['a_lease']['today'] = Item.where('cat1 = 1 AND cat2 = 2 AND cat3 = ? AND created_at >= ? AND created_at <= ?', n, tday.beginning_of_day.in_time_zone("London"), tday.end_of_day.in_time_zone("London")).count()
        @data[n]['a_lease']['yday'] = Item.where('cat1 = 1 AND cat2 = 2 AND cat3 = ? AND created_at >= ? AND created_at <= ?', n, yday.beginning_of_day.in_time_zone("London"), yday.end_of_day.in_time_zone("London")).count()

        @data[n]['b_sale']['today'] = Item.where('cat1 = 2 AND cat2 = 1 AND cat3 = ? AND created_at >= ? AND created_at <= ?', n, tday.beginning_of_day.in_time_zone("London"), tday.end_of_day.in_time_zone("London")).count()
        @data[n]['b_sale']['yday'] = Item.where('cat1 = 2 AND cat2 = 1 AND cat3 = ? AND created_at >= ? AND created_at <= ?', n, yday.beginning_of_day.in_time_zone("London"), yday.end_of_day.in_time_zone("London")).count()
        @data[n]['b_lease']['today'] = Item.where('cat1 = 2 AND cat2 = 2 AND cat3 = ? AND created_at >= ? AND created_at <= ?', n, tday.beginning_of_day.in_time_zone("London"), tday.end_of_day.in_time_zone("London")).count()
        @data[n]['b_lease']['yday'] = Item.where('cat1 = 2 AND cat2 = 2 AND cat3 = ? AND created_at >= ? AND created_at <= ?', n, yday.beginning_of_day.in_time_zone("London"), yday.end_of_day.in_time_zone("London")).count()

        @data[n]['c_sale']['today'] = Item.where('cat1 = 3 AND cat2 = 1 AND cat3 = ? AND created_at >= ? AND created_at <= ?', n, tday.beginning_of_day.in_time_zone("London"), tday.end_of_day.in_time_zone("London")).count()
        @data[n]['c_sale']['yday'] = Item.where('cat1 = 3 AND cat2 = 1 AND cat3 = ? AND created_at >= ? AND created_at <= ?', n, yday.beginning_of_day.in_time_zone("London"), yday.end_of_day.in_time_zone("London")).count()
        @data[n]['c_lease']['today'] = Item.where('cat1 = 3 AND cat2 = 2 AND cat3 = ? AND created_at >= ? AND created_at <= ?', n, yday.beginning_of_day.in_time_zone("London"), tday.end_of_day.in_time_zone("London")).count()
        @data[n]['c_lease']['yday'] = Item.where('cat1 = 3 AND cat2 = 2 AND cat3 = ? AND created_at >= ? AND created_at <= ?', n, yday.beginning_of_day.in_time_zone("London"), yday.end_of_day.in_time_zone("London")).count()

        @data[n]['d_sale']['today'] = Item.where('cat1 = 4 AND cat2 = 1 AND cat3 = ? AND created_at >= ? AND created_at <= ?', n, tday.beginning_of_day.in_time_zone("London"), tday.end_of_day.in_time_zone("London")).count()
        @data[n]['d_sale']['yday'] = Item.where('cat1 = 4 AND cat2 = 1 AND cat3 = ? AND created_at >= ? AND created_at <= ?', n, yday.beginning_of_day.in_time_zone("London"), yday.end_of_day.in_time_zone("London")).count()
        @data[n]['d_lease']['today'] = Item.where('cat1 = 4 AND cat2 = 2 AND cat3 = ? AND created_at >= ? AND created_at <= ?', n, tday.beginning_of_day.in_time_zone("London"), tday.end_of_day.in_time_zone("London")).count()
        @data[n]['d_lease']['yday'] = Item.where('cat1 = 4 AND cat2 = 2 AND cat3 = ? AND created_at >= ? AND created_at <= ?', n, yday.beginning_of_day.in_time_zone("London"), yday.end_of_day.in_time_zone("London")).count()

        @total_today = Item.where('created_at >= ? AND created_at <= ?', tday.beginning_of_day.in_time_zone("London"), tday.end_of_day.in_time_zone("London")).count()
        @total_yday = Item.where('created_at >= ? AND created_at <= ?', yday.beginning_of_day.in_time_zone("London"), yday.end_of_day.in_time_zone("London")).count()
      end
    end
  end

What happens when I try to open this page in the app is that the page either doesn't load at all (timeout) or it loads, but it takes close to 30 seconds.
I tried to add indeces to the cat1, cat2, cat3 and created_at columns, but it didn't help.
There's a possibility that the number of rows in the table items will grow to ~1M in the next 3-4 months.
How do I generate stats about the data from the tables of similar sizes? Also, I realize the code above might not appear to look very intelligent - I tried to put something together quickly (I am happy to learn how to generate stats better, though).

You're going to have to use explain and see why your indexes aren't being used. Also, if the underlying data isn't changing, you should consider caching the results.

This is tangential, but you should be using scopes to encapsulate your query logic. Item.where('cat1 = 4 and cat2 = 1') should be a scope, so you can just call Item.commercial_sales and add additional where clauses to it. You can also use ranges, ie where(created_at: (start..end)) to generate a between clause.

A query like this would make more sense here: select count(*) as count, cat1, cat2, cat3 from items where created_at between ? and ? group by cat1, cat2, cat3.

You are doing 360 database queries on this page. Of course, this is slow. I suggest trying to combine multiple scopes into one and running the count queries, for example, with group(:cat3, :cat1, :cat2). How strict are you about the output format?

but it didn't help., why do you think it was a problem in the first place? You didn't share any query plan, no indication at all that there is an issue with indexes. Could you please share the results from explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) for one of your queries? And the DDL for all tables and indexes involved. All in plain text, as an update of your question.

Depending on how the results are to be used generating statistics from a pseudo-random sample may meet requirements and would of course be much faster.

@spickermann I am quite flexible, I just need to visualize it on the dashboard (I am currently displaying the data in <table>)

in addition to the other good suggestions, let me add that a small performance improvement can be obtained with "date(created_at) = ?",Time.now.in_time_zone("London").to_date" for today's results and add .advance(days: -1) for yesterday's. Instead of using between

Untested but too long for a comment.
The following should work for you (if not I will remove it)
@data =Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = Hash.new(&h.default_proc) }
tday = Date.today.end_of_day.in_time_zone("London")
yday = (tday - 1.day).beginning_of_day.in_time_zone("London")
items = Item.where(created_at: yday..tday)
              .group(Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('CAST',[Item.arel_table[:created_at].as('DATE')]).to_sql,
                    :cat1,:cat2,:cat3)
              .count

l_tday = tday.to_date
l_yday = yday.to_date

(1..20).each do |n|
  
  @data[n]['a_sale']['today'] = items.fetch([l_tday,1,1,n], 0)
  @data[n]['a_sale']['yday'] = items.fetch([l_yday,1,1,n], 0)
  @data[n]['a_lease']['today'] = items.fetch([l_tday,1,2,n], 0)
  @data[n]['a_lease']['yday'] = items.fetch([l_yday,1,2,n], 0)
 #...
end 
# optionally you could issue a separate query to collect the totals
@total_today = items.sum {|k,v| k.include?(l_tday) ? v : 0 }

We are querying all items created between yesterday beginning of day and today end of day and grouping them by the created_date as date, cat1, cat2, and cat3 and count each group. (1 query)
Then we iterate over the range 1..20 and just look up the groups by [date,cat1,cat2,n] where n represents cat3

That first line Hash.new is pretty cool. Still trying to figure it out... :p

@Maxence translated into words this line would be something like: "Create a new Hash. For each new key that is added to this Hash assign its value as a new Hash. For each new key that is added to this Hash assign its value to a new Hash, ad infinitum."

Yes got the idea. Though never thought a hash could be hiding something. Really thought it was a stateless dictionary. I also get the proc converted to a block. Just need to read about the default_proc thing too... Not metaprogramming but not often seen.

ActiveRecord has a set of methods for collecting aggregates (#count, #sum etc) however they are not very good for anything but trivial use cases. Using count in a loop is a very poor approach for almost any problem as you're creating N number of database queries.
In Postgres 9.4+ we can use FILTER to get the count for a single day:
SELECT 
  COUNT(items.*) FILTER (
    date_trunc('day', 'created_at') = CURRENT_DATE - 1
  ) AS yday,
  COUNT(items.*) FILTER (
    date_trunc('day', 'created_at') = CURRENT_DATE
  ) AS today
FROM items
WHERE date_trunc('day', 'created_at') >= CURRENT_DATE - 1

This example assumes that you're using UTC internally in the database and that we can ignore the timezone. Otherwise you can use AT TIME ZONE to cast to a timezone.
To get the values per category combination you can apply a grouping:
SELECT 
  items.cat1,
  items.cat2,
  items.cat3,
  COUNT(items.*) FILTER (
    date_trunc('day', 'created_at') = CURRENT_DATE - 1
  ) AS yday,
  COUNT(items.*) FILTER (
    date_trunc('day', 'created_at') = CURRENT_DATE
  ) AS today
FROM items
GROUP BY cat1, cat2, cat3
WHERE date_trunc('day', 'created_at') >= CURRENT_DATE - 1

You can use this SQL together with Item.connection.select_all to get the data as raw results (hashes).
However if your table is going to grow significantly it would be wise to consider defining a view which can be described kind of like a table that the database populates by running a SQL query as this will be much more performant than querying the aggregates with every request. In Rails you can use the scenic gem to define views in migrations.

Note that this answer is intended as a nudge in the right direction and not a copy paste solution. The question is lacking an example of the data, schema and output needed to actually give that kind of answer.
